# Cloud cover fraction

Tags: curated-data

I need to make use of Mathematica's `WeatherData` functionality, the `CloudCoverFraction` property, specifically. However, it does not seem to work. I need to know this fraction for New York City on, let's say, 1 December 2013, so I entered the command `clouds = WeatherData["New York", "CloudCoverFraction", {2013, 12, 1}]`. The result was a time series with 36 data points - but when I tried to retrieve the values with `clouds["Values"]`, I only got `{Missing["NotAvailable"],..., Missing["NotAvailable"]}`. The result is similar when I try e.g. London. Is this a bug or I'm doing a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Same result here. These data seems indeed to be not available (but for example it works if you replace `CloudCoverFraction` with `Pressure`).

Comment: However if you ask WolframAlpha `WolframAlpha["new york cloud cover december 1 2013", "ComputableData"]` it seems to be available.

Comment: @SquareOne, the WolframAlpha query works (which I didn't know) but the problem is that I need the values for approx. 600 days (consecutive) as I'm studying effects of weather on some other phenomena. I guess I would have to run the query for every single day...?

Comment: It seems that with WolframAlpha you cannot get more than one month of data at once, for example `WolframAlpha["new york cloud cover december 2013", "ComputableData"]`. So for a whole year you'll just have to call that 12 times by changing the name of the month of course. Then of course you'll have to group all the data ...

Comment: If you go back to 2009 or earlier, you get numbers for cloud cover.  Perhaps it is related to the dates of the sources here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/WeatherDataSourceInformation.html.  It suggests that recent weather data is not included in the curated `WeatherData`.  Seems odd to me, since some recent data is available.

Answer (score 1):

I get 34 data points of which 6 are not `Missing`:

```
clouds = WeatherData["New York", "CloudCoverFraction", {2013, 12, 1}]

clouds["Values"] // DeleteMissing
(* {1, 1, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75} *)

DateListPlot[DeleteCases[clouds["Paths"], {_, _Missing}, {2}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize -> 0.02, Joined -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might want to prefer using `DeleteMissing[clouds["Paths"], 2]` instead of the `DeleteCases` above if you have v10.0 or higher.